# Why calling assigned lambda is faster than calling function and lambda (not assigned)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, performance, lambda

Why calling an assigned lambda in python3.11 is faster than:

- calling function
- lambda that isn't assigned

Why this happens only (maybe) on python 3.11 and not 3.7?

I tried this:

```py
Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> def test():
...     return 100 * 1000
...
>>> test2 = lambda: 100 * 1000
>>>
>>> print(timeit("test()", globals=globals()), timeit("test2()", globals=globals()), timeit("lambda: 100 * 1000"))
0.04339419997995719 0.039589399995747954 0.04896240000380203
```

and this:

```py
Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 16:30:00) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> def test():
...     return 100 * 1000
...
>>> test2 = lambda: 100 * 1000
>>> print(timeit('test()', globals=globals()), timeit('test2()', globals=globals()), timeit('lambda: 100 * 1000'))
0.05223070000000973 0.05272850000000062 0.03326450000000136
```

I don't know is it my fault or python interpreter.
**Why on python3.11 assigned lambda call is faster that function and unassigned lambda call?**
**Does this mean that lambdas should be assigned for better performance or is it just an error on python3.11?**

Comment: Your third test is timing *defining* a `lambda`, not calling it. And your timings are so close together that I'm fairly sure it's timing jitter (changing the order of the tests, or even the *name* of the tests might be enough to change the timings).

Comment: it runs automatically when defined, doesn't it?

Comment: Why do you think it would do that? `lambda`s are called when *called*. If you passed an actual `lambda` to `timeit` (`timeit(lambda: 100 * 1000)`), not a string describing one, I believe it would call it, but it won't *both* `eval` the string *and* call the result of `eval`-ing it.

Comment: sure , besides the incorrectness of just defning a lambda, this is full of jitter - calling `timeit` on similar statements here get me variations of more than 100% between consecutive calls.
For the record , the `assigned lambda` and `defined function` are the same bytecode and internal-runtime-wise.

Comment: Is this proper test?:
python3.7:
```
>>> print(timeit('(lambda: 100 * 1000)()'))  
0.09047160000000076
```
python3.11:  
```
>>> print(timeit('(lambda: 100 * 1000)()'))  
0.10210430005099624
```

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as "a lambda". Lambda expressions define `function` objects, just like `def` statements. Syntactic limitations prevent lambda expressions from defining *all* functions that `def` statements can, but for those it can define, there is no significant difference from the equivalent function produced by a corresponding `def` statement.

Comment: Metadata aside, `x = lambda ...: ...` is equivalent to `def x(...): return ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the incorrectness of just defining a lambda and not calling it, as stated in the comments, this test is full of jitter - calling `timeit` on similar statements on my box get me variations of more than 100% between consecutive calls ,and even more than 30% with 10_000_000 runs (instead of the default 1_000_000 runs).

For the record , the assigned lambda and defined function are the same bytecode and internal-runtime-wise -as you can check by disassembling both:

```
In [39]: from dis import dis

In [40]: def test():
    ...:     return 1 + 2
    ...: 

In [41]: test2 = lambda: 1 + 2

In [42]: dis(test)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              4 RETURN_VALUE

In [43]: dis(test2)
  1           0 RESUME                   0
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```